# Does GraphQL work with default variables?

Tags: sites-9, graphql, content-service, pca

I'm trying to use the new GraphQL features of the content service in Tridion 9. The following GraphQL query works fine:

```
  {
    page (cmUri:"tcm:10-1310-64")
    {
      lastPublishDate,
      title
    }
  }
```

This returns something like this:

```
  {
    "data": {
      "page": {
        "lastPublishDate": "2019-01-09T17:53:01.893+01:00",
        "title": "My page"
        }
    }
  }
```

Next, I want to use variables in the query (see https://graphql.org/learn/queries/ for information). My new GraphQL query goes like this:

```
  query myquery($uri: String) {  
    page (cmUri:$uri) {
      lastPublishDate,
      title
    }
  }
```

When I make this request, I need to add a query variable called uri to the request, and it still works like a charm!

So far all good. Now, I want to define a default value for my '$uri' variable in the query:

```
  query myquery($uri: String = "tcm:10-1310-64") {  
    page (cmUri:$uri) {
      lastPublishDate,
      title
    }
  }
```

When I run this query without query parameters, I would expect the default value (tcm:10-1310-64) to be used. Instead, I get the following response from the server:

```
  {
    "timestamp": 1548255295101,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "java.lang.NullPointerException",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/cd/api"
  }
```

The content service's core log has this:

```
2019-01-23 15:54:55,100 ERROR [http-nio2-8081-exec-5] [dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is 
java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at     graphql.execution.ValuesResolver.coerceArgumentValues(ValuesResolver.java:77)
at graphql.execution.Execution.execute(Execution.java:71)
at graphql.GraphQL.execute(GraphQL.java:554)
at graphql.GraphQL.parseValidateAndExecute(GraphQL.java:496)
...
```

It seems as if the content service is unable to resolve default variables.

Is this perhaps a bug? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me, I'm able to reproduce this issue my side.

if the graphql query used variables in parameters then always expected to send the value of the query **variables** to be **{}**.  if we pass query **variables** value to be **null** then this issue occurs.

Expected Request:

> {"query":"query myquery($uri: String = \"tcm:5-394-64\") \n{  \n
>   page (cmUri:$uri) {\n      id,\n    \titemId,\n
>   \tlastPublishDate,\n      title,\n    \turl,\n    \ttaxonomies{\n
>   id,key,title\n      }\n    }\n 
>   }\n",**"variables":{}**,"operationName":"myquery"}

[image]

> {"query":"query myquery($uri: String = \"tcm:5-394-64\") \n{  \n
>   page (cmUri:$uri) {\n      id,\n    \titemId,\n
>   \tlastPublishDate,\n      title,\n    \turl,\n    \ttaxonomies{\n
>   id,key,title\n      }\n    }\n 
>   }\n",**"variables":{"uri":"tcm:5-295-64"}**,"operationName":"myquery"}

[image]

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, Velu. I don't quite understand why I have to pass an empty variable array but you are correct, it works this way.