# GraphQL does not return titles of categories and keywords

Tags: sites-9, graphql, content-service, pca

The public content API (GraphQL) does not appear to return titles of categories or keywords. The following query works, but the titles show up as null:

```
{
  categories(namespaceId: 1, publicationId: 10) {
    edges {
      cursor,
      node {
        itemId,
        title,
        itemType,
        children {
          edges {
            cursor,
            node {
              itemId,
              title,
              itemType
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the response I get:

```
{
  "data": {
    "categories": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "cursor": "MQ==",
          "node": {
            "itemId": 29,
            "title": null,
            "itemType": 512,
            "children": {
              "edges": [
                {
                  "cursor": "MQ==",
                  "node": {
                    "itemId": 1425,
                    "title": null,
                    "itemType": 1024
                  }
                },
                {
                  "cursor": "Mg==",
                  "node": {
                    "itemId": 1431,
                    "title": null,
                    "itemType": 1024
                  }
                },
                {
                  "cursor": "Mw==",
                  "node": {
                    "itemId": 1251,
                    "title": null,
                    "itemType": 1024
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

From Velu's answer to my previous GraphQL question (see [Does GraphQL work with default variables?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/19713/does-graphql-work-with-default-variables/19728#19728)), I gather that he has the same problem.

The category which contains the keywords has been published.

Am I doing something wrong (again) or is it a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hotfix **CD_11.0.0.13730.zip** is now available for this issue (via FTP or it can be requested from Support as well).

Comment: Great news, I will try it out asap.

Comment: It's a bit later, but this query worked nicely with Tridion Sites 9.6. +1 to the question and answer. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I get similar results in my Sites 9 setup. It could be a bug because I also cannot filter on keyword title, only on keyword key.

However you can request the Keyword **key** to be part of the response:

```
{
  categories(namespaceId: 1, publicationId: 5) {
edges {
  cursor,
  node {
    itemId,
    title,
    itemType,
    children {
      edges {
        cursor,
        node {
          itemId,
          title,
          itemType,
          key              
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Philippe. Using keys instead of titles might be a work-around in some cases, but the big problem is that you don't have to give them a value (where as titles are mandatory).